# All the trace() function calls in ActionScript 3.0 stopped running using Flash Pro CS5?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I follow some sample code which uses

```
trace("Hello World");
```

to print out something in ActionScript 3.0, in Flash Professional CS5.

But nothing seems to get printed out (in a browser).  Is the trace() function deprecated / removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using the developer version of the flashplayer then the trace function is output to a log file somewhere on your system (depending on os and flash player) [see here for notes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=logging_04.html) otherwise there are programs that output things via javascript, i use [thunderbolt](http://code.google.com/p/flash-thunderbolt/) to talk to firebug in firefox, but there are others out there that do similar things.

Answer (score 1):

The `trace` function exists for testing applications when you are creating them in the Flash CS5 IDE. You should be using the Test Movie option to run your movie when you want to have these messages put on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your trace messages in your FLASH CS5 IDE output window, but you can't see it in your swf